# Правила Iptables не работают с прокси-маршрутизацией

Tags: ubuntu, маршрутизация, iptables

У меня Raspberry Pi 4, и на этом устройстве я запустил прокси-сервер на порту 6075, eth0 подключен к Интернету и имеет адрес 20.20.20.64. Также точка доступа подключена к интерфейсу wlan0 и имеет IP-адрес 192.168.4.1. DHCP включен для хостов wlan0 (192.168.4.0/24). Когда я подключаюсь к точке доступа, я хочу подключиться к Интернету (eth0) через свой прокси-сервер (порт: 6075). Как это реализовать с помощью iptables?
Это правило не работает.
DNAT tcp -- 192.168.4.0/24 0.0.0.0/0 TCP dpt:80 до:20.20.20.64:6075
DNAT tcp -- 192.168.4.0/24 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:443 to:20.20.20.64:6075
Цепочка POSTROUTING (политика ACCEPT)
целевая прибыль, выбор, источник, место назначения
МАСКАРАД все -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

Пробовал перенаправить трафик с помощью DNAT и SNAT.

Comment: А с самого устройства интернет видно ? Если с маршрутизацией все ок, то ваш прокси должен видеть интернет. А если его видит прокси, то и ваши клиенты подключающиеся к этому прокси так же должны все увидеть. NAT тут вообще не причем. Он используется если у вас нет никакого прокси и вы хотите пробросить интернет напрямую.